# Cannot alter disk partitions with any tool on brand new PNY SSD

Tags: ssd, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption, diskpart

I have a brand new PNY 120gb SSD with less than 2 days of runtime since I opened the box. It is running in a Dell E6520 laptop with a fresh copy of Windows 10 Professional 64 bit.

I installed this drive because the last one died abruptly. The last SSD started becoming corrupt and sluggish, then it died with a BSOD and BCD errors. After trying to diagnose it the drive stopped being recognized at all and I wrote it off as dead.

So I installed this PNY and within 2 days it is also corrupt, BSOD, and giving me BCD errors. I boot into WinRE and cannot get SFC /scannow to work. I removed the drive to try in another computer and SFC /scannow will not run on this drive. I tried starting the Windows Module Installer and TrustedInstaller services manually. That did not help.

Then I tried running chkdsk. I could not get it to run on the machine itself, but in another machine I successfully fixed 12 disk errors. I then tried the disk again in the original machine and still kept getting errors.

I removed the drive again and tried running all the usual bootrec commands. The rebuildMBR and fixBCD commands also fail.

So I tried going back to WinRE on the original machine and tried reformatting and reinstalling Windows once again. This time as a UEFI disk. To do that I run mbr2gpt on the drive and this fails as well.

So once again I remove the drive from the original machine and drop it in another machine. This time I'm going to use DiskPart to completely delete everything on this drive.

I literally JUST ran the following commands.....

```
LIST DISK
SELECT DISK 5
LIST PART
SELECT PARTITION 1
DELETE PARTITION OVERRIDE
SELECT PARTITION 2
DELETE PARTITION OVERRIDE
SELECT PARTITION 3
DELETE PARTITION OVERRIDE
```

Diskpart returns "DiskPart successfully deleted the selected partition" each time. Yet when I relist the partitions they all remain completely unchanged.

I want to blame the SSD drive itself, but I have a sneaking suspicion that this is the fault of the original laptop corrupting and possibly damaging the drives.

Does anyone have any suggestions that I could test?

Comment: It's unusual to find such a high failure rate with SSDs.  I wonder if the initial symptoms (BSODs and BCD errors) are from something else, like a software issue.  If you have time to spare, I suggest downloading a fresh Windows 10 ISO, making a clean installation, and installing nothing but Chrome for a few days.  If it still works, install programs and make changes slowly until it starts breaking.

Comment: If you're OK with losing all data on the disk, I suggest using DISKPART, SELECT DISK #, CLEAN .

Comment: I tried using the media creation tool 1909 to make two boot devices. 2 days prior windows was installed on this drive from the same media successfully. Both are uninstallable. The windows installer cannot delete or format the partitions on the disk. Diskpart clean fails. I'm learning towards there being something popped on the motherboard that's damaging these things.

Answer (score 1):

How about a different tool?

Download [Ubuntu's ISO file](https://ubuntu.com/download).

The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be [checked for download errors](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0).

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on [a Linux PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0) or on [a Windows PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0).

Once you make a LiveUSB, boot with it. When the desktop appears, run [GNOME Disks](https://linuxhint.com/gnome_disk_utility/) and use it to delete the unwanted partitions on the disk. It often succeeds when DISKPART fails.

Comment: @zelon88 If this worked, please click on the checkmark to the left of the answer; if not, please let us know

Comment: This did not work. Nothing works. I'm convinced that the drive is just a brick. It fails SMART scans for Unknown Attribute 170 which is "Reserved Block Count." I'm thinking that the laptop in question has experienced a controller failure and is causing the disks to eat up their spare sector pool within hours. I cannot do anything with this drive and I've tried half a dozen machines so far.